# ExecuteSqlCommand automatically calls SaveChanges() when I don't want it to

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

In my ASP.NET MVC project using Entity Framework 5, I have one operation that I want to perform with a back-end stored procedure, because it affects a number of different entities. The nature of the stored procedure is that I don't need or want it to be tracked by EF; I call it from one entity, and then that entity's values are copied into a different table in the database. The problem is that I can't seem to **stop** EF from calling SaveChanges(), even though I don't want it to.

Here's a truncated version of my repository code:

```
public class SubmissionRepository : IRepository<RebateHeaderSubmission>
    {
        private readonly HbaRebatesContext _db;

        public SubmissionRepository()
        {
           _db = new HbaRebatesContext();
        }

        public void Add(RebateHeaderSubmission entity) . . .
        public RebateHeaderSubmission GetById(int id) . . .
        public IQueryable<RebateHeaderSubmission> GetAll() . . .
        public void Update(RebateHeaderSubmission entity) . . .

        public void Save()
        {
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void AcceptSubmission(RebateHeaderSubmission entity)
        {
            var param = new SqlParameter("Rebate_Entry_Id", entity.Id);
            _db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC dbo.AcceptSubmission @Id", param);
        }
    }
}
```

And here's a slightly-truncated version of the code that calls `AcceptSubmission()`:

```
public ActionResult Edit(RebateHeaderSubmission editedRecord, bool acceptSubmission = false)
{
    if (editedRecord.Id > 0 && ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _db.Update(editedRecord);
    }
    else
    {
        return PartialView("_Edit", editedRecord);
    }

    _db.Save();

    if (acceptSubmission == false)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Single", new { id = editedRecord.Id });
    }
    else
    {
        var repo = _db as SubmissionRepository;
        if (repo != null)
        {
            repo.AcceptSubmission(editedRecord);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Single", new { id = editedRecord.Id });    
    }
}
```

But in `AcceptSubmission()`, as soon as `_db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` is called, the execution jumps up to the `Save()` method and I get a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` saying that no rows were updated.

I've tried updating the method to detach the entity, but it hasn't done any good. This was the attempt I was most hopeful about:

```
public void AcceptSubmission(RebateHeaderSubmission entity)
{
    try
    {
        var param = new SqlParameter("Rebate_Entry_Id", entity.Id);
        var context = ((IObjectContextAdapter)_db).ObjectContext;
        context.SaveChanges();
        context.Detach(entity);
        _db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC dbo.AcceptSubmission @Rebate_Entry_Id", param);
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        //Do nothing for now.
    }
}
```

The execution still jumps up to `Save()`, and my catch block doesn't even work, because the exception happens in the `Save()` method instead. Is there anyway to get EF to stop calling `SaveChanges()`?

UPDATE: Two small clarifications. First, the stored procedure I'm calling *is* being executed, and it works. So `AcceptSubmission()` is working. Second, when I say that execution "jumps" to `Save()`, what actually happens is that as soon as I've run `_db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand`, an exception is raised, but it's raised in the `Save()` method. I don't actually hit the end bracket for `AcceptSubmission()`, nor the opening bracket for `Save()`.

Comment: Your description doesn't make sense to me. If execution jumps to Save() then somewhere in your code you are calling Save(). The problem isn't that EF is calling SaveChanges(), it is that when SaveChanges is being called no rows were updated when EF thinks they should be

Comment: @Colin I completely agree -- it doesn't make sense. But I don't see anywhere in my code that I'm calling it, and when I debug, the very next thing that happens after pressing "Step Into" on `_db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` is that a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` is raised, but it's in the `Save()` method, not `AcceptSubmission()`.

Comment: I've updated with a better explanation of what's actually happening.

Comment: Before you call `AcceptSubmission`, you already call `_db.Save()`. So even if `AcceptSubmission` did call `Save()` somewhere, it wouldn't matter, as there wouldn't be any changed entities left.

Comment: @hvd Fair point. I just added that because I was trying to be extra-super-sure that EF knew the object was saved, but that's admittedly silly. But actually, playing around with that may have led me to the answer. It may be that the code isn't jumping around, but the the `Save` method is taking a long time to finish executing. Unfortunately, I won't be able to finish looking into this until tonight. Thanks for getting me pointed in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was mis-diagnosing the problem. EF wasn't "jumping" to `SaveChanges`. There were actually two active threads, caused by an error with Unobtrusive JavaScript, such as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13476254/visual-studio-2012-mvc-3-multiple-unwanted-threads). Fixing the error in my JavaScript fixed the problem.